# XML Deserialize returning 0 results in c#

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, xml-deserialization

hoping someone can point out what I'm missing here. I'm trying to deserialize the result of a SOAP API call.

I have the following InnerXML within the soapenv:Body of the result

```xml
<ns2:OperationResponseInfo xmlns:ns2="http://www.XXXXX.com/webservice/">
    <status>
        <statusCode>0</statusCode>
        <statusDesc>No Error</statusDesc>
    </status>
    <result>
        <record>
            <param>
                <name>totalrecord</name>
                <value>9</value>
            </param>
        </record>
    </result>
    <result>
        <record>
            <param>
                <name>ALARMID</name>
                <value>1581807719208</value>
            </param>
            <param>
                <name>ALARMDESC</name>
                <value>xxxxxxxxxxxxxx</value>
            </param>
            <param>
                <name>ALARMSTATUS</name>
                <value>Unacknowledged</value>
            </param>
        </record>
    </result>
</ns2:OperationResponseInfo>
```

I am trying to deserialize to the following objects :-

```
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "OperationResponseInfo", Namespace = "http://www.XXXXX.com/webservice/")]
    public class OperationResponseInfo
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "status")]
        public Status Status { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "result")]
        public List<Result> Result { get; set; }

        //[XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ns2", Namespace = "http://www.XXXXX.com/webservice/")]
        //public string Ns2 { get; set; }
    }


    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "status")]
    public class Status
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "statusCode")]
        public string StatusCode { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "statusDesc")]
        public string StatusDesc { get; set; }
    }


    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "result")]
    public class Result
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "record")]
        public List<Record> Record { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "record")]
    public class Record
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "param")]
        public List<Param> Param { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "param")]
    public class Param
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the deserialize method I am using

```
    public class Serializer
{
    public T Deserialize<T>(string input) where T : class
    {
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer ser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(input))
        {
            return (T)ser.Deserialize(sr);
        }
    }
```

and this is the call to the Deserialize method

```
var alarmList = ser.Deserialize<OperationResponseInfo>(docInner.InnerXml);
```

I have this working on another system (with different SOAP result format/c# classes etc.) but for some reason the Deserialize is returning 0 results. The code desn't error at all. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespaces and inheritance rules between `xmlns=...`, namespace aliases, and what `XmlSerializer` assumes; try:

```cs
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "status", Namespace = "")]
    public Status Status { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "result", Namespace = "")]
    public List<Result> Result { get; set; }
```

More specifically:

- when using `xmlns="..."`, namespaces are *inherited* by descendants
- when using `ns2:blah`, that prefix is *not* inherited by descendants - it must be explicit
- so `<status>` and `<result>` are in the empty namespace
- but `XmlSerializer` assumes that namespaces are inherited by default, so `[XmlElement(ElementName = "status")]` means "an element called `status` in the same namespace as the current context, i.e. `http://www.XXXXX.com/webservice/`"
- so you need to explicitly tell `XmlSerializer` to go back to the *empty* namespace